# Apple Maps & E-Z Pass (detection?)

Tags: ios, maps

I've been driving a bit lately up and down the east coast of the United States and I realized that Apple Maps constantly tells me to "stay left" when going through tolls.

Every toll that I have gone through has E-Z Pass only lanes on the far left.  Some of them split up early so if you get into the left lane you're stuck there.

**Does Apple Maps detect the E-Z Pass in my car?**

If I was more oblivious while driving and I didn't have one, I could end up with some hefty fines.

Comment: The states of Delaware and Massachusetts do not charge you a yearly maintenance fee. You get the device for a one time fee plus a deposit for you eventual tolls.  You do not have to live in these states to get the E-Z Pass.

Answer (score 4):

Well I do not have E-Z Pass and it sent me to the left and I couldn't get out of it and I had to pay a $60 fine instead of an $8 toll fee.

Comment: It seems like an answer that "no" - it's not aware of which of several toll lanes you should choose.

Comment: The same thing happened to me in Delaware. Being unfamiliar with this area, I was already confused about where to go for a Cash payment lane, when Siri repeatedly told me to get in the left lane. Doing this landed me in an Easy Pass Lane with no way out when I spotted the Cash lane on the far right, which resulted in a $1 toll turning into a $50 fine!

Answer (score 2):

I don't think so.

I'm not aware of any such feature on the iPhones or Apple Maps and haven't been able to find anything on the matter to definitively say either way, so I can be totally wrong even though I haven't found anything to suggest that's the case.

Moving on to this "keep left" thing - I can't explain it. I can be driving down a straight freeway with no exits in sight and Siri will tell me to keep left for seemingly no reason.

Take it as an unintentional friendly reminder to get in the E-Z Pass lane and hope they don't patch it. ;)